# Get children without subchildren

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML I have tables in tables.
So I have for example a table in a td element.

However when getting all td's for the closest row :

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
```

I am getting all the subchildren also (all td elements in the child table).

How you get all childs without sub elements ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `$(this).closest('tr').find('>td');`

The **>** only select direct descendants (first level children)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `children()`:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
```

Or alternatively include the direct descendant selector when using `find()`:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('> td');
```